# "Round" 2530.30 to 2599 in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, math, rounding

I need to replace numbers like `2530.30` with `2599` in PostgreSQL.

I tried using `ROUND(2530.30)+0.99` but it only changes the numbers after the decimal point to `99`. So it results in `2530.99`, which I don't want.

I want to remove fractional digits and replace the last two decimal digits with 99. I know I can just use an `integer`, but my assignment at school says I need to do this.

There should no be negative numbers, the assignment says that I should have a product that is sold for, let's say, 3500.50 dollars, I then need to make this number go from `3500.50` to `3599`. Not `3500.99`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 100, truncate, multiply by 100 again:

```
SELECT trunc(2530.30 / 100) * 100 + 99;
```

This replaces all numbers in the range `[2500, 2600)` with `2599`.
Or, in more general terms, it replaces the last two decimal digits with `99` and discards fractional digits (which also transforms `0` or `12.50` to `99`).

Negative numbers cannot occur, as you say, so ignored.